# How can I write DRY golang map manipulation functions

Tags: dictionary, go, dry

As far as I know, golang has no type variables. So how can I DRY out these two functions?

```
func merge_modes32(nm map[uint32]pb.Mode, om map[uint32]pb.Mode) {
    for k, v := range nm {
        om[k] = v
    }
}

func merge_modes64(nm map[uint64]pb.Mode, om map[uint64]pb.Mode) {
    for k, v := range nm {
        om[k] = v
    }
}
```

Comment: In Go it is considered fine to repeat yourself in this way as far as I know

Comment: Those functions are "DRY" already.

Comment: Are you guys trolling?

Comment: no they are not, there good are reasons about that. However you can still use reflection to achieve dryness. You can search for something similar to this https://github.com/clementauger/st

Answer (score 3):

You can't "dry" that in a way that will be close in performance. You could use reflection, but the resulting code will be drastically slower.

What to do? Until generics arrive (maybe in Go 2?), you may keep creating such functions for all required types, or just use the `for` loop where it's needed. It's just 3 lines of code including the loop and brackets...